# Can I combine all Groovy sources to one script?

Tags: groovy

I have a project on Groovy, which is built with Maven. Can I somehow on build step to merge all files with a source code into a single Groovy script for delivery to the end user?

Comment: You can generate a single Jar file if that's what you mean?  With Maven you'd use the shade plugin, and with Gradle you'd use the Shadow plugin.  Not 100% what you have or what you need though, your question is pretty vague...

Comment: tim_yates no, i mean one `*.groovy` file

Comment: Seems like an odd thing to do, but the scripts are just text, so you could merge them unless you have imports and grapes, then you'd probably have to have some smarts around the merge.

Comment: External Java application connects and executes this Groovy script using the Groovy Shell. Will I be able in this case to use imports like a `import my.pkg.MyGroovyClass`?

Comment: I can't think of any way that's resilient to do what you want to do...  `cat *.groovy >> bigFile.groovy` doesn't feel like it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is impossible. Another way is use `evaluate`:

```
evaluate(new File("../tools/Tools.groovy"))
```